# Changing Java EE version in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee

I downloaded Java EE 6 and it installed with no errors.  I am attempting this tutorial from Sun:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf-jpa-crud-wizard.html

The problem is that I have no idea how to change Netbeans to allow me to use Java EE version 6.  I am still only offered 5.

This is where I downloaded Java EE 6:

http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/index.jsp

How do I get Netbeans to recognize the newer version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may be a heavyweight solution but you can download the newest version of netbeans (6.8) which has out-of-the-box support for EE 6.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Netbeans 6.8](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/), when you create a new Enterprise Application (using the Java EE project type), the third step allows you to choose between JavaEE6, JavaEE5 and J2EE1.4.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You apparenly have an older version of Netbeans and installed Glassfish v3 separately. You need at least [Netbeans 6.8](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/) for this. In the 2nd [link](http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/index.jsp) which you have posted yourself, there's even a download button in the top to get Netbeans 6.8 with Glassfish v3 (a Java EE 6 implementation) bundled.

Answer (score 0):

When you say *"I downloaded Java EE 6"*, I guess that what you actually mean is that you downloaded GlassFish v3 (an implementation of the Java EE 6 specification). That being said:

- You don't need Java EE 6 support for the tutorial you are mentioning.
- You can deploy the code of the tutorial on GlassFish v3 (which you have downloaded).
- There is GlassFish v3 support in NetBeans 6.7 to start/stop/deploy on the GlassFish v3 server (install the *GlassFish v3 Enabler* plugin).
- If you actually don't want to strictly follow the tutorial and experiment Java EE 6 features, then you'll need to install NetBeans 6.8 (maybe pick up a Java EE 6 tutorial in this case, for example [this one](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted.html)).